# Only unit test methods not get displayed on list box, while calling unit test methods

Tags: c#

I am calling Unit Test Methods from another project to a window form list.
But I am getting 'ToString','Equals' etc. along with test methods.

This is my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FillListView();
}

public void FillListView()
{
    MethodInfo[] methodInfoFT = typeof(UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);

    foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfoFT)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(methodInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [In .NET, can you use reflection to get all non-inherited methods of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880819/in-net-can-you-use-reflection-to-get-all-non-inherited-methods-of-a-class)

Comment: I tried to keep declared only on binding but it does not solved

Comment: It works for me. Show what you tried.

Comment: I missed Instance part and was replacing with InvokeMethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DeclaredOnly` binding flag to ensure that you only retrieve the methods defined in the class itself.

```
 MethodInfo[] methodInfoFT = typeof(UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```