# Can you extend the default JsonConverter used in JSON.NET for collections?

Tags: c#, json.net, base-class, default-implementation

I'm trying to write a custom JsonConverter for cases where a person subclasses a list or collection, but then adds extra properties to the subclass (see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5863496/168179)).  The current implementation of JSON.NET just changes the list into an array of child objects and ignores all of the added properties.  So I want to write a new JsonConverter that treats the object as if it *wasn't* a List and to just serialize everything else as normal, but then to add a new property in the serialization called '_Items' where the actual array of data is stored.

Now I've already written a class that does exactly this for our specific List subclass, but I had to manually specify all the properties one-by-one.  But if I could write a converter that treats this just as a normal object, then manually handle the items, I'd be golden.  I don't even care if I end up duplicating half of another class (or even more!) but I'd love to make a reusable converter for these cases.  However, as I said, I can't find the default converter to start from.

So... anyone know where that is?

Comment: See [How do I get json.net to serialize members of a class deriving from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21265629/10263)

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it does give me an idea of how to go.

Answer (score 16):

There is no 'default converter' in JSON.NET.

If you are able to examine the [JsonSerializerInternalWriter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs) class, look at the `SerializeValue` method. In it, there is the 'converter find and perform' phase at the top. However, if there is no converter that matches, it resorts to the contract type serialization (the switch statement).

I haven't found a way (a correct way or a graceful hack) to be able to perform a generic contract serialization (ex: parsing an object as normal)  with an extended custom serialization on an entity (which I assume you are trying to do).

Comment: Kind of crazy that this has never been fixed so the default logic is correctly factored into a DefaultJsonConverter.

Answer (score 4):

[As @dbc said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616648/7094638), you can override `CanRead` and `CanWrite` to return `false` and register `CustomAsDefaultConvertor : JsonConverter` for your property.

My case:

```
public class AsDefaultConverter : JsonConverter<JObject>
{
    public override JObject ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JObject existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, JObject value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanRead => false;
}
```

MyModel:

```
public class MyModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets event id
    /// </summary>
    public string EventId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets trigger name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets arguments
    /// </summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AsDefaultConverter))]
    public JObject Arguments { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets trigger creation date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets trigger creator
    /// </summary>
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

In startUp registration I have overrided default JsonSerialization on my custom, but for property `JObject Arguments` I have specified converter that I need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure since when and if this is the answer but there is property `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` which seem used to get `JsonSerializerSettings` internally

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm