# How to use default serialization in a custom JsonConverter

Tags: json, json.net

I have a complex object graph that I am serializing/deserializing with Json.NET. Some of the objects derive from an abstract class, so in order for the deserialization to work properly, I needed to create a custom `JsonConverter`. Its only role is to select the appropriate concrete implementation of the abstract class at deserialization-time and allow Json.NET to continue on its way.

My problem comes when I want to serialize. I don't need to do anything custom at all. I want to get exactly the same behavior as I would get using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` with no custom `JsonConverter`.

However, since I'm using the custom JsonConverter class for my deserialization needs, I'm forced to supply a `WriteJson` implementation. Since WriteJson is abstract, I can't just call `base.WriteJson`, but I want to do essentially that. So my question is, what do I put in that method to get the plain-Jane, default behavior? In other words:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    // What goes here to get default processing?
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just turn on `TypeNameHandling` to `Auto` in your serializer settings? This will add a "$type" property if an instance type is different than its declaring property type (which will be an interface or base class type). Isn't this exactly what you want?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In your custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm), override [`CanWrite`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) and return false:

```
public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you can just throw an exception from `WriteJson`, since it won't get called.

(Similarly, to get default behavior during **de**serialization, override [`CanRead`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanRead.htm) and return `false`.)

Note that the same approach can be used for [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1.htm) (introduced in [Json.NET 11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1)) since it is just a subclass of `JsonConverter` that introduces type-safe versions of [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1_ReadJson_1.htm) and [`WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_1_WriteJson_1.htm).

Comment: It was too obvious :). Thanks!

Comment: Ohh that CanWrite.... it's a pity it wasn't more clear even in the doc ;). Totally forgot about looking at the base type. Thank's

Comment: It is very stupid. This is contraries to solid principles