# Json.NET JsonConverter is chosen for serialization even if CanWrite returns false

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a bunch of custom `JsonConverter`s where some are in charge of serialiation, and some of deserialization. I add them to a `JsonSerializer` using the `Converters` property.

My problem is that if I have one `JsonConverter` for serializing a specific type, and another for deserializing the same type, the correct `JsonConverter` is not chosen for the specific task, it is always the first one in the list of `Converters`, where CanConvert returns true, that is chosen, regardless of whether that `JsonConverter` `CanWrite` or not.

In the below example, both `CustomConverterA` and `CustomConverterB` CanHandle the `string` type, but only `CustomConverterB` can write (the only difference is that `CanWrite` returns true for `CustomConverterB`). I would expect `CustomConverterB` to be chosen.

But `CustomConverterA` is chosen, however its `WriteJson` method is never called. `CustomConverterB` is skipped entirely since `CustomConverterA` was chosen before it.

```
public class CustomConverterA : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterA.CanWrite (returns false)");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterA.CanConvert");

        if (objectType == typeof(string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("return true");
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("return false");
        return false;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterA.WriteJson");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterA.ReadJson");

        return new object();
    }
}

public class CustomConverterB : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterB.CanWrite (returns true)");
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterB.CanConvert");

        if (objectType == typeof(string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("return true");
            return true;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("return false");
        return false;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterB.WriteJson");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside CustomConverterB.ReadJson");

        return new object();
    }
}

public void TestCustomConverter()
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer()
    {
        Converters = {
            new CustomConverterA(),
            new CustomConverterB()
        }
    };

    var data = "testdata";

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
        var serialized = writer.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Serialized: " + serialized);
    }
}
```

The above example outputs:

```
Inside CustomConverterA.CanConvert
return true
Inside CustomConverterA.CanWrite (returns false)
Serialized: "testdata"
```

Are `JsonConverter`s supposed to work like this? Am I not supposed to be able to have different classes handle serialization and deserialization? If not, what is the purpose of the `CanWrite` and `CanRead` properties?

Comment: it might be checking CanConvert for choosing converter https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#Converters

Comment: Rather than falling back to the second converter, when `CanConvert` returns `false`, Json.NET falls back to default serialization, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616648/3744182).  You can confirm this in the source code for [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L164).

Comment: Yes, it seems like it only chooses the first JsonConverter where CanConvert returns true, regardless of whether it CanWrite or not. My opinion is that this is unexpected behaviour. I'll post an issue in the GitHub repo.