# How to deserialize collection of interfaces when concrete classes contains other interfaces

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I am currently facing the situation where I get a json file that I can't modify and I want the resulting deserialized class to be generic for design purpose.

First here are my interfaces :

```
public interface IJobModel
{
    string ClientBaseURL { get; set; }
    string UserEmail { get; set; }
    ExportType Type { get; set; }
    List<IItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public interface IItemModel
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string ImageSize { get; set; }
    string ImagePpi { get; set; }
    List<ICamSettings> CamSettings { get; set; }
}

public interface ICamSettings
{
    string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Then here is the code I design to tackle my problem :

```
public class ThumbnailJobModel : IJobModel
{
    [JsonProperty( "clientBaseURL" )]
    public string ClientBaseURL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "userEmail" )]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "type" )]
    [JsonConverter( typeof( TypeConverter ) )]
    public ExportType Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "items" )]
    [JsonConverter( typeof( ConcreteConverter<List<IItemModel>, List<Item>> 
) )]
    public List<IItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ThumbnailJobModel()
    {
        Type = ExportType.Thumbnails;
        Items = new List<IItemModel>();
    }

    public class Item : IItemModel
    {
        [JsonProperty( "id" )]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty( "imageSize" )]
        public string ImageSize { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty( "imagePpi" )]
        public string ImagePpi { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty( "shoots" )]
        //[JsonConverter( typeof( CamSettingsConverter ) )]
        [JsonConverter( typeof( ConcreteConverter<List<ICamSettings>, 
List<ShootSettings>> ) )]
        public List<ICamSettings> CamSettings { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {
            CamSettings = new List<ICamSettings>();
        }
    }

    public class ShootSettings : ICamSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty( "orientation" )]
        [JsonConverter( typeof( OrientationConverter ) )]
        public Orientation Orientation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty( "clothShape" )]
        [JsonConverter( typeof( ClothShapeConverter ) )]
        public Shape Shape { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty( "fileName" )]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public ShootSettings()
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Perspective;
            Shape = Shape.Folded;
            FileName = null;
        }
    }

    public enum Orientation
    {
        Perspective = 0,
        Oblique = 1,
        Front = 2,
        Back = 3,
        Left = 4,
        Right = 5,
        Up = 6,
        Down = 7
    }

    public enum Shape
    {
        Folded = 0,
        Hanger = 1,
        Mannequin = 2
    }

    public class ConcreteConverter<I, T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
        {
            return typeof( I ) == objectType;
        }

        public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader,
         Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>( reader );
        }

        public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer,
            object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class OrientationConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            string enumString = (string)reader.Value;

            return Enum.Parse( typeof( Orientation ), enumString, true );
        }

        public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
        {
            return objectType == typeof( string );
        }

        public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, 
JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ClothShapeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            var enumString = (string)reader.Value;

            return Enum.Parse( typeof( Shape ), enumString, true );
        }

        public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
        {
            return objectType == typeof( string );
        }

        public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, 
JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class TypeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            return ExportType.Thumbnails;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
        {
            return objectType == typeof( string );
        }

        public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, 
JsonSerializer serializer )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public static void HandleDeserializationError( object sender, 
ErrorEventArgs errorArgs )
    {
        errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        var currentObj = errorArgs.CurrentObject as ShootSettings;

        if ( currentObj == null ) return;

        currentObj.Orientation = Orientation.Perspective;
        currentObj.Shape = Shape.Folded;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a list of `ICamSettings` in the `IItemModel` interface.

I try to deserialize this json into my `ThumbnailJobModel` class :

```
{
 "clientBaseURL":"https://clientName.fr",
 "userEmail":"myName@gmail.com",
 "items":[
   {
      "id":"11913",
      "imageSize":"1280,720",
      "imagePpi":"72",
      "shoots":[
         {
            "fileName":"front1.png",
            "orientation":"front",
            "clothShape":"hanger"
         },
         {
            "fileName":"folded1.png",
            "orientation":"front",
            "clothShape":"folded"
         },
         {
            "fileName":"right1.png",
            "orientation":"right",
            "clothShape":"hanger"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2988",
      "imageSize":"1280,720",
      "imagePpi":"",
      "shoots":[
         {
            "fileName":"perspective1.png",
            "orientation":"perspective"
         }
      ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I deserialize my json like that :

```
//Read the job config
string jobConfig = File.ReadAllText( jsonConfigPath );
IJobModel m_jobModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ThumbnailJobModel>( 
jobConfig );
```

And the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception : Error setting value to 'CamSettings' on 
'IWD.Screenshoter.Job.ThumbnailJobModel+Item'.
Stack :
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.SetValue 
(System.Object target, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0 
  at 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue 
(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property, 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object target) [0x00000] in 
<filename unknown>:0 
  at 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject 
(System.Object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id) 
[0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I honestly don't understand what I am doing wrong, I hope someone will be able to throw some light on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is that your `ConcreteConverter<I, T>` is designed to deserialize something declared as an interface as a concrete type -- e.g. `IItemModel` as `Item` -- but you are not using it in that way.  You are using it to deserialize a concrete list of interfaces as a concrete list of concrete types, e.g.:

```
[JsonProperty( "items" )]
[JsonConverter( typeof( ConcreteConverter<List<IItemModel>, List<Item>>) )]
public List<IItemModel> Items { get; set; }
```

Instead, you should apply the converter to the *items* of the `Items` and `CamSettings` collections using [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) like so:

```
public class ThumbnailJobModel : IJobModel
{
    [JsonProperty("items", ItemConverterType = typeof(ConcreteConverter<IItemModel, Item>))]
    public List<IItemModel> Items { get; set; }
```

And

```
public class Item : IItemModel
{
    [JsonProperty("shoots", ItemConverterType = typeof(ConcreteConverter<ICamSettings, ShootSettings>))]
    public List<ICamSettings> CamSettings { get; set; }
```

This should fix the exception.  However, there are additional suggestions to be made:

- In several converters you have no implementation for `WriteJson()`.  If you want to use default serialization, you can [override `CanWrite` and return `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29616648/3744182).
- Please rename `TypeConverter` to `ExportTypeConverter`.  `TypeConverter` is already used for [something else](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).
- `OrientationConverter` and `ClothShapeConverter` are unnecessary, the built-in [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) will serialize and deserialize any enum as a string.

  If you want an exception to be thrown for numeric enum values, you could subclass it as `StrictStringEnumConverter` and set [`AllowIntegerValues = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter_AllowIntegerValues.htm):

  ```
  public class StrictStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
  {
      public StrictStringEnumConverter() { this.AllowIntegerValues = false; }
  }
  ```

  You could also make `ExportTypeConverter` inherit from `StringEnumConverter` so as to get the desired serialization behavior.
- In `ConcreteConverter` since `T` is supposed to be a concrete implementation of `I`, you can add a `where` constraint to make sure users of the type don't accidentally invert the generic arguments:

  ```
  public class ConcreteConverter<IInterface, TConcrete> : JsonConverter where TConcrete : IInterface
  {
  }
  ```

  I also renamed the generic arguments to something more meaningful.
- In several converters you override `CanConvert(Type)` and test for the incoming type being a `string`, where `string` was the type serialized to the file:

  ```
  public override bool CanConvert( Type objectType )
  {
      return objectType == typeof( string );
  }
  ```

  When applied directly by attributes, `CanConvert()` is never called.  When applied by settings, during serialization `objectType` is the actual type of the object that is about to get serialized.  And when applied by settings, during deserialization `objectType` is the declared type of the member whose value is about to get deserialized.  It's never the type in the file.  Thus in `ExportTypeConverter` it should be written as follows:

  ```
  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
      return objectType == typeof(ExportType);
  }
  ```

  Or, since the converter is only ever applied by attributes, you could just throw a `NotImplementedException`.
- I don't see any reason to nest models like `Item` inside `ThumbnailJobModel`.  To me it simply causes additional complexity.  You could just make them non-public instead.  But this is just a matter of opinion.

Putting all that together you code should look something like:

```
public interface IJobModel
{
    string ClientBaseURL { get; set; }
    string UserEmail { get; set; }
    ExportType Type { get; set; }
    List<IItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public interface IItemModel
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string ImageSize { get; set; }
    string ImagePpi { get; set; }
    List<ICamSettings> CamSettings { get; set; }
}

public interface ICamSettings
{
    string FileName { get; set; }
}

public enum ExportType
{
    Thumbnails,
}

public class ThumbnailJobModel : IJobModel
{
    [JsonProperty("clientBaseURL")]
    public string ClientBaseURL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userEmail")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ExportTypeConverter))]
    public ExportType Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items", ItemConverterType = typeof(ConcreteConverter<IItemModel, Item>))]
    public List<IItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ThumbnailJobModel()
    {
        Type = ExportType.Thumbnails;
        Items = new List<IItemModel>();
    }

    public class Item : IItemModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("imageSize")]
        public string ImageSize { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("imagePpi")]
        public string ImagePpi { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shoots", ItemConverterType = typeof(ConcreteConverter<ICamSettings, ShootSettings>))]
        public List<ICamSettings> CamSettings { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {
            CamSettings = new List<ICamSettings>();
        }
    }

    public class ShootSettings : ICamSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty("orientation")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(StrictStringEnumConverter))]
        public Orientation Orientation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("clothShape")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(StrictStringEnumConverter))]
        public Shape Shape { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fileName")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public ShootSettings()
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Perspective;
            Shape = Shape.Folded;
            FileName = null;
        }
    }

    public enum Orientation
    {
        Perspective = 0,
        Oblique = 1,
        Front = 2,
        Back = 3,
        Left = 4,
        Right = 5,
        Up = 6,
        Down = 7
    }

    public enum Shape
    {
        Folded = 0,
        Hanger = 1,
        Mannequin = 2
    }

    public class ConcreteConverter<IInterface, TConcrete> : JsonConverter where TConcrete : IInterface
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(IInterface) == objectType;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
         Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<TConcrete>(reader);
        }

        public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class ExportTypeConverter : StringEnumConverter
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            reader.Skip(); // Skip anything at the current reader's position.
            return ExportType.Thumbnails;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(ExportType);
        }
    }

    public class StrictStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
    {
        public StrictStringEnumConverter() { this.AllowIntegerValues = false; }
    }

    public static void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs errorArgs)
    {
        errorArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        var currentObj = errorArgs.CurrentObject as ShootSettings;

        if (currentObj == null) return;

        currentObj.Orientation = Orientation.Perspective;
        currentObj.Shape = Shape.Folded;
    }
}
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/npbHxT).

Comment: Hello dbc, really sorry for the delay :/
Super easy to understand and absolutely brilliant solution, it works like a charm !! Thanks a bunch.