# How to convert JSon to IPoint type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a JSON file where on of the properties is:

```
"Location": {
  "Latitude": 38.7080404,
  "Longitude": -9.1436747
}
```

And I have a few classes with a Location property:

```
public class Example {
  public IPoint Location { get; set; }
}
```

A IPoint can be created as follows:

```
Example example = new Example();
example.Location = new Point(new Coordinate(latitude, longitude)) { SRID = 4326 };
```

How can I define a Newtonsoft JSon.Net rule to convert from JSON to any property of type IPoint?

Comment: Minor issue, `IPoint` is an interface, JSON Deserializer will fail because it cannot instantiate an interface

Comment: But it can initialize a class and I mentioned that it should be created a Point instance. But if necessary I can change the property from IPoint to Pont

Comment: Assuming you always want to create a `Point` type for your `IPoint` property, you could use `ConcreteConverter<IPoint, Point>` from [How to deserialize collection of interfaces when concrete classes contains other interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47939878), e.g. by adding it to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`.  For other options see [Using Json.NET converters to deserialize properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2254872).  In fact this may be a duplicate, agree?