# How to fix InvalidCastException while using JsonConverter for an IList of Interfaces?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonconvert

I am trying to create an abstraction layer for Json.NET deserialization using interfaces.
To achieve this I use custom `JsonConverter` which works just fine, until interfaces are introduced.
Following exception is thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error
>   setting value to 'Items' on 'BatchList'. --->
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List1[BatchItems]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IBatchItems]

This is the setup to repro in a console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonBatch = @"{'items': [{'Id': 'name1','info': {'age': '20'}},{'Id': 'name2','info': {'age': '21'}}]}";
        DeserializeAndPost(jsonBatch);
    }

    public static void DeserializeAndPost(string json)
    {
        IBatchList req;
        req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BatchList>(json);
        Post(req);
    }

    public static void Post(IBatchList batchList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(batchList.Items.FirstOrDefault().Id);
    }
}

public interface IBatchList
{
    List<IBatchItems> Items { get; set; }
}

public interface IBatchItems
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    JObject Info { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class BatchList : IBatchList
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Items", Required = Required.Always)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<BatchItems>))]
    public List<IBatchItems> Items { get; set; }

}

[JsonObject]
public class BatchItems : IBatchItems
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Info", Required = Required.Always)]
    public JObject Info { get; set; }
}

// JsonConverter

public class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<T> list = (List<T>)value;
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            value = list[0];
        }
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be deserialized JSON as I provide the type for the interface to be used for deserialization:

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<BatchItems>))]
```

to be used.
Instead, `unhandled cast exception` is being thrown.

Note that if I use instead `SingleOrArrayConverter<IBatchItems>`, I will get an exception

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type
```

as the `[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<BatchItems>))]` is meant to provide concrete type for the following interface: `public List<IBatchItems> Items { get; set; }`.

Comment: What happens if you specify `SingleOrArrayConverter<IBatchItems>` instead?

Comment: You will get
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type`as the `[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<BatchItems>))]` is meant to provide concrete type for the following interface: `public List<IBatchItems> Items { get; set; }` as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to combine the functionality of the following two converters:

1. `SingleOrArrayConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/3744182) to *[How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182)* by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers).

   This converter handles the frequently-encountered case where a one-item collection is not serialized as a collection; you are already using this converter.
2. `ConcreteConverter<IInterface, TConcrete>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47945131/3744182) to *[How to deserialize collection of interfaces when concrete classes contains other interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47939878/3744182)*.

   This converter deserializes a declared interface (here `IBatchItems`) into a specified concrete type (here `BatchItems`).  This is required because `IList<T>` is not [covariant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/) and thus an `IList<BatchItems>` cannot be assigned to a `IList<IBatchItems>` as you are currently trying to do.

The best way to combine these two converters is to adopt the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and enhance `SingleOrArrayConverter` to encapsulate a converter for each of the list's items inside the list converter:

```
public class SingleOrArrayListItemConverter<TItem> : JsonConverter
{
    // Adapted from the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n
    // By Brian Rogers, dbc et. al.

    readonly JsonConverter itemConverter;
    readonly bool canWrite;

    public SingleOrArrayListItemConverter(Type itemConverterType) : this(itemConverterType, true) { }

    public SingleOrArrayListItemConverter(Type itemConverterType, bool canWrite)
    {
        this.itemConverter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(itemConverterType);
        this.canWrite = canWrite;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(List<TItem>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContent().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        var list = (ICollection<TItem>)(existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator());
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            list.Add(ReadItem(reader, serializer));
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            while (reader.ReadToContent())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.EndArray:
                        return list;
                    default:
                        list.Add(ReadItem(reader, serializer));
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Should not come here.
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unclosed array at path: " + reader.Path);
        }
    }

    TItem ReadItem(JsonReader reader, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (itemConverter.CanRead)
            return (TItem)itemConverter.ReadJson(reader, typeof(TItem), default(TItem), serializer);
        else
            return serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return canWrite; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = value as ICollection<TItem>;
        if (list == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid type for {0}: {1}", GetType(), value.GetType()));
        if (list.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
                WriteItem(writer, item, serializer);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in list)
                WriteItem(writer, item, serializer);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }

    void WriteItem(JsonWriter writer, TItem value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (itemConverter.CanWrite)
            itemConverter.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        else
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}

public class ConcreteConverter<IInterface, TConcrete> : JsonConverter where TConcrete : IInterface
{
    //Taken from the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939878/how-to-deserialize-collection-of-interfaces-when-concrete-classes-contains-other
    // by dbc
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IInterface) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<TConcrete>(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
            reader.Read();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }

    public static bool ReadToContent(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (!reader.Read())
            return false;
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
            if (!reader.Read())
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then apply it as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class BatchList : IBatchList
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Items", Required = Required.Always)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayListItemConverter<IBatchItems>), typeof(ConcreteConverter<IBatchItems, BatchItems>))]
    public List<IBatchItems> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- This version of `SingleOrArrayListItemConverter<TItem>` avoids pre-loading the entire array into a `JToken` hierarchy which may improve performance.
- If `IBatchItems` later becomes polymorphic, you could replace `ConcreteConverter` with a converter that intelligently selects the concrete type to use based on the properties present as shown in e.g. the answers to *[Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182)* and *[How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YhCWAI).

Comment: This is fire. Thanks. Works perfect.