# Best way to upgrade JSON field to a class structure

Tags: json, json.net

Just wondering if anyone knows of the best way to upgrade a JSON structure Deserialisation to a new class type.

To further explain the legacy value was

```
        public string author;
```

this has now been updated in the api to the following

```
 public class Author
{
    public string name;
    public string email;
    public string url;
}

public Author author;
```

So now I have an issue where any legacy data does not deserialize into this correctly as it used to be a string and now its a class.

My current solution is if it fails to deserialize then to do it into a class that had the old structure and then use this to go into the new one, but i feel there must be a better way to cast the old sting value into the new class value as part of the process.

Thanks

EDIT-1:

Ok i have made some headway with a converter below

```
public class AuthorConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Author user = (Author)value;
        writer.WriteValue(user);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Author author = new Author();

        Debug.Log(objectType + "  " + reader.Value);
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            author.name = (string) reader.Value;
        }
        else if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            try
            {
                JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

                if (jObject.TryGetValue("name", out JToken name))
                {
                    author.name = name.Value<string>();
                }
                if (jObject.TryGetValue("email", out JToken email))
                {
                    author.email = email.Value<string>();
                }

                if (jObject.TryGetValue("url", out JToken url))
                {
                    author.url = url.Value<string>();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e);
                throw;
            }

        }
        return author;
    }
```

Appears to all be working, but feels a bit fiddly to have to get the values 1 by 1 and convert over, i tried using the jObject.ToObject method but appeared to cause an infinite loop. Either way its working, but im sure there is a better way, so still open for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Author` has a default (parameterless) constructor, you can avoid having to populate each property manually by using [`JsonSerializer.Populate(JsonReader, Object)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm).  And to avoid having to write your own `WriteJson()` method, override [`CanWrite`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) and return false.

Thus your converter can be rewritten as follows:

```
public class AuthorConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(Author); }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null; // Or throw an exception if you don't want to allow null.
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
                return new Author { name = (string) reader.Value };
            else
            {
                var author = new Author();
                serializer.Populate(reader, author);
                return author;
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    // Skip past any comments to the next content token, asserting that the file was not truncated.
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    // Read (advance to) the next token, asserting that the file was not truncated.
    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Json.NET [supports comments in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm) despite the fact that they are not part of the JSON standard.  The serializer ignores comments but they must be manually skipped when writing a converter.
- `JsonReader` will throw an exception on most types of malformed JSON (e.g `{"a":"b"]`) but will not throw an exception for a truncated file, so converters should not assume that expected tokens are read successfully.
- See also *[Json.NET custom serialization with JsonConverter - how to get the "default" behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35586987/3744182)* and *[How to use default serialization in a custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29616596/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1HlpG5).