# Use ItemTypeNameHandling on a single object instead of on a list

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to get newtonsoft json to add type information a object that is not in a list.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zhm0SQ

Essentially I want the type info to be stored on the CommandTest property in the same way it handles the collection.

Is there a different attribute that can be used in the same way?

Comment: Are you just looking for [`JsonPropertyAttribute.TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_TypeNameHandling.htm) instead of [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm)?  See e.g. [How to automatically include type information when serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043728/3744182) which seems to cover your case exactly.  I updated your fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIPqNw) and it now runs successfully.

Comment: yes! Couldn't find it last night. Thank you.