# Serialize subclass with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to use Json.NET to serialize a subclass. The resulting json contains the serialized properties for the superclass but **not** the properties on the subclass object.

This seems to be related to an issue I found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5863496/498969). But having to write a `JsonConverter` seems like overkill.

**Sample subclass:**

```
public class MySubclass : List<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample of the serialization:**

```
MySubclass myType = new MySubclass() { Name = "Awesome Subclass" };
myType.Add("I am an item in the list");

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myType, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

**Resulting json:**

```
[
  "I am an item in the list"
]
```

I expected to result to be more like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Awesome Subclass",
    "Items": [
        "I am an item in the list"
    ]
}
```

Perhaps I am just not using the right configuration when serializing. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am trying to move away from an XmlSerializer for multiple reasons, but mainly for performance. Currently I am serializing objects using an XmlSerializer and implementing `IXmlSerializable` because I have complex generic interface properties that are being serialized (which can't be deserialized without implementing `IXmlSerializable`). Json.NET is fast and it will allow me to serialize/deserialize this same object without having to do custom serialization. The downside is that I just found out it won't serialize properties on a subclass of `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationGuide.htm):

> .NET lists (types that inherit from `IEnumerable`) and .NET arrays are
>   converted to JSON arrays. Because JSON arrays only support a range of
>   values and not properties, **any additional properties and fields**
>   declared on .NET collections **are not serialized**.

So, don't subclass `List<T>`, just add a second property.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public MyClass() { Items = new List<string>(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the note from the documentation. It looks like I can't use the classes that I was using for XmlSerialization unless I modify them so that they no longer inherit from an `IEnumerable` class.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my thoughts on this.  I would think that your expected results would be more consistent with a class like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I would not expect to see an `Items` element in the serialized result for `MySubclass : List<string>` since there is no Items property on `List` nor on `MySubclass`.

Since your class `MySubclass` is actually a list of strings, I would guess (and I am just guessing here) that the `SerializeObject` method is merely iterating through your object and serializing a list of strings.