# .Net properties are missing in the response got from AngularJs Ajax call to Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am making an ajax call using AngularJS $http to Asp.Net Web Api.

```
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat',
                    params: dataTemp,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.modelObject.resultData = response.data;
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    $scope.modelObject.result = response;
                });
```

The web api action has the following signature

```
public PaginatedList<PatientCategory> PatCat(PaginatedRequestCommand cmd){...}
```

The PaginatedList type is as follows.

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPageCount { get; private set; }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPageCount);
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed the ctor as its not required here. So its just a wrapper to a list of T and in this case T is PatientCategory.

I am able to access the list from the response object after the ajax call. But I am not able to find the properties of the PaginatedList such as 
PageIndex, PageSize and so on in the response object. Even as I use fiddler, I can clearly see the array of PatientCategory objects but as the properties of the PaginatedList are missing.

```
[{"Id":1,"Code":"H05120000003","Name":"Regular","Description":"The Regular Patient Category","ModifiedTime":"2015-10-01T19:34:33.727","History":null,"MyXmlColumn":null},{"Id":2,"Code":"BH130000001","Name":"STAFF_CHGD_TO_REGULAR","Description":null,"ModifiedTime":"2015-10-01T19:46:07.093","History":null,"MyXmlColumn":null},{"Id":3,"Code":"BH130000001","Name":"STAFF_CHGD_TO_REGULAR","Description":null,"ModifiedTime":"2015-10-01T19:52:03.773","History":null,"MyXmlColumn":null}]
```

**So how can I access those properties as well in the response?**

The request and response that show up in Fiddler are as follows.

Request

```
GET http://localhost:50849/api/PatientCategoryApi/PatCat?Page=1&Take=3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50849
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:50849/PatientCategory/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 479
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQlZIXEF2YmhIaXNcQXZiaEhpcy5XZWJcYXBpXFBhdGllbnRDYXRlZ29yeUFwaVxQYXRDYXQ=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 01:43:57 GMT

[{"Id":1,"Code":"H05120000003","Name":"Regular","Description":"The Regular Patient Category","ModifiedTime":"2015-10-01T19:34:33.727","History":null,"MyXmlColumn":null},{"Id":2,"Code":"BH130000001","Name":"STAFF_CHGD_TO_REGULAR","Description":null,"ModifiedTime":"2015-10-01T19:46:07.093","History":null,"MyXmlColumn":null},{"Id":3,"Code":"BH130000001","Name":"STAFF_CHGD_TO_REGULAR","Description":null,"ModifiedTime":"2015-10-01T19:52:03.773","History":null,"MyXmlColumn":null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net web api use NewtonJson.dll to make a Javascript serialization. When newtonjson find a class implement IEnumerable, it will serialize this object to an Javascript object like this [{},{}], it seems newtonjson only serialize the IEnumebrable object, other properties are ignored. Also you can add the NewtonSoft.Json.JsonObject to the class PagenatedList, this attribute will tell newtonjson serialize the data to a javascript plain object like this {p1: "", p2: ""}, but you will find the IEnumebrable data lost. To solve this, you should custom a new CustomJsonConverter inherited from JsonConverter, and add the attribute to your PagenatedList like this:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))
public class PagenatedList<T>:List<T>
//your class code
```

Comment: See here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383736/json-net-with-custom-collection-with-collection-properties

Comment: Oh..no, thats not a good news. Any way as I search, there seems to be no other option. i thought some simple tweak in the $http ajax call would do the job.

Comment: Or you can try modify your custom class "PaginatedList", change it from inherit from a list to contain a "List" property.