# Newtonsoft Json Serialisation of a Dictionary with custom properties

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have the following C# code, using Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.6:

```
void Main() {
    var data=new AllData();
    var cst=new CustomerData();
    cst.CustomerName="Customer1";
    cst.Add(1, new UserData() {UserName="User1", UserPhone="123456789"});
    cst.Add(2, new UserData() {UserName="User2", UserPhone="987654321"});
    data.Add(1, cst);

    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

public class UserData {
    public string UserName;
    public string UserPhone;
}

public class CustomerData:Dictionary<int,UserData> {
    public string CustomerName;
}

public class AllData:Dictionary<int,CustomerData> {}
```

So from this code I'm expecting to see this output:

```
  {
    "1": {
      "CustomerName": "Customer1",
      "1": {
        "UserName": "User1",
        "UserPhone": "123456789"
      },
    "2": {
      "UserName": "User2",
      "UserPhone": "987654321"
      }
    }
  }
```

But instead I'm seeing:

```
{
  "1": {
    "1": {
      "UserName": "User1",
      "UserPhone": "123456789"
    },
  "2": {
    "UserName": "User2",
    "UserPhone": "987654321"
    }
  }
}
```

i.e. My CustomerName property is ignored.

I've played with the Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization and Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty attributes without success and so am wondering where to look now. A full custom serialisation implementation seems like overkill, is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383736/json-net-with-custom-collection-with-collection-properties

Comment: Inheriting from `List<T>` or `Dictionary<T>` is considered code smell. Is there any reason you couldn't get away without inheriting `Dictionary<T>`?

Comment: @AndyJ - I'm aware of custom serialization, it seems like there should be a simpler way though, hence my question

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I could have a property for the dictionary, but this makes the Json serialization more complex as I'd want to omit the property name. I could have a private dictionary and have my own accessor methods but that complicates my example, so I chose inheritance to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Would JsonExtensionDataAttribute be suitable? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-as-part-of-its-parent-object-using-json-net

Comment: @AndyJ It appears that JsonExtensionDataAttribute is just for deserialization... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The first bit of text in that link says it does both :S "Instructs the JsonSerializer to deserialize properties with no matching class member into the specified collection and write values during serialization."

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis Can you add a reference to why it would be considered a code smell? I would love to read more about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [JsonExtensionDataAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm) that JSON.Net provides to put any properties that don't exist on the parent object in to the collection property.

Here's an example taken from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893614/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-as-part-of-its-parent-object-using-json-net).

JSON:

```
{
    "X" : "value",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

C# Data Object:

```
public class Test
{
    public string X { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Y { get; set; }
}
```

Key1 and Key2 will end up in the Dictionary because they don't exist in the class "Test, where as X will end up in the X property.

It's not perfect, it seems you have to have a Dictionary of type Dictionary, but it still might be a better option that using a custom serializer?

Here's an [example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ctMvu8) using one level of your data classes.

For the data:

```
public class UserData
{
    public string UserName;
    public string UserPhone;
}

public class CustomerData
{
    public string CustomerName;

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Users;
}

var data = new CustomerData()
{
    CustomerName = "Foo",
    Users = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
    {
        { "1",  new UserData() { UserName = "Fireman", UserPhone = "0118 999 881 999 119 725 ... 3" } },
        { "2",  new UserData() { UserName = "Jenny", UserPhone = "867-5309" } }
    }
};
```

It produces the JSON:

```
{
    "customerName": "Foo",
    "1": {
        "userName": "Fireman",
        "userPhone": "0118 999 881 999 119 725 ... 3"
    },
    "2": {
        "userName": "Jenny",
        "userPhone": "867-5309"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, I see how you can use it. Many thanks @AndyJ, this is a nice neat solution :-)

Comment: No probs, I'm glad you got it sorted :)