# Properties of extended dictionary won't show in serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I extended a dictionary (which is perfect data structure for translations) and added a marker telling what kind of translation will be performed.

```
internal class Translation : Dictionary<string, string>
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I serialize the object, I only get the key-value pairs in my output string. The name doesn't show. I wanted to use the stuff from the goodie bag from uncle Microsoft, i.e. [*System.Text.Json*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#how-to-write-net-objects-to-json-serialize), so I do the following.

```
string output = JsonSerializer.Serialize(source);
```

My suspicion is that I will need to implement a custom serializer but that's way too much hustle for this simple case. My experience tells me there's a neat, smooth approach bundled in the tools (one that I'm simply not aware of).

How to do it? Alternatively, if not possible smoothly, why is it a complex matter (that I'm apparently failing to appreciate)?

I was expecting a JSON on form below.

```
{
  "name": "donkey",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
}
```

I can resolve it by adding an item to my dictionary with *key* being *name* and *value* being *donkey*, of course. But that pragmatic solution, I prefer to save as my fall-back. At the moment I have some extra time and want to play around with the structure. Also, I can imagine that the *name* might become an *int* instead of *string* or maybe even a more complex structure to describe e.g. timestamp or something. That would totally break the contract of the dictionary (being string-to-string mapping).

Comment: Do you want to stick to the native `System.Text.Json` or are you up to use json.net ?

Comment: @Cid For this case, I want to try out the new goodies. [Checking the performance](https://michaelscodingspot.com/the-battle-of-c-to-json-serializers-in-net-core-3/), there's no bigger risk in switching and it offers an opportunity to broaden the competence. Since time isn't of much concern (Christmas holidays and stuff), I can afford to waste some effort without my boss lurking over my shoulder, hehe. Otherwise, I'd go with Newton due to extensive blogization around it.   :)

Comment: This can be the same issue explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383736/how-to-serialize-deserialize-a-custom-collection-with-additional-properties-usin) for newtonsoft.json. You may have to go with a custom converter

Comment: However, a lazy workaround could be to change the structure of your class, instead of extending a `Dictionary<string, string>`, use that as a class property

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys

Comment: Does your sample work? Because there are a lot of GitHub issues (like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40120) or [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41283)) showing that attempts to serialize a dictionary can cause `NotSupportedException`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It works (as in no exceptions). It lacks the extra field, though, so it works unsatisfactorily.   :)

Comment: @HansPassant Does that relate to the new JSON converter from *System.Text.Json*? I'm not sure if I understand the point of the link provided. Are you saying that it can't be done regardless, due to how a dictionary inheritance works?

Comment: @KonradViltersten There are a lot of unfinished things in `System.Text.Json`, per GitHub. I've got the same behavior for `List<string>`, extended property isn't serilaized, using custom converter seems to be only one option here, at least for now. There are some examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#support-dictionary-with-non-string-key)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But... but... it's Christmas... And it's supposed to be a goodie bag from Microsoft and uncle Billy G... Maybe I got too excited and went ahead of myself on this one.   :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the design intent -- as with Newtonsoft, `JavaScriptSerializer` and `DataContractJsonSerializer`, the dictionary keys and values are serialized, not the regular properties.

As an alternative to extending `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you can get the JSON you want by encapsulating a dictionary in a container class and marking the dictionary with [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute):

```
internal class Translation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

And then serialize as follows:

```
var translation = new Translation
{
    Name = "donkey",
    Data = 
    {
        {"key1", "value1"},
        {"key2", "value2"},
        {"key3", "value3"},
    },
};

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    // Other options as required
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(translation, options);
```

Do note this restriction from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

> The dictionary's TKey value must be [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netcore-3.1), and TValue must be [JsonElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement) or [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object).

(As an aside, a similar approach would work with Newtonsoft which has its own [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm).  If you are using both libraries, be sure not to get the attributes confused.)

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BfO4l3).

If this modification to your data model is not convenient, you can introduce a custom [`JsonConverter<Translation>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1) that (de)serializes a DTO like the model above, then maps the DTO from and to your final model:

```
internal class Translation : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class TranslationConverter : JsonConverter<Translation>
{
    internal class TranslationDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public override Translation Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TranslationDTO>(ref reader, options);
        if (dto == null)
            return null;
        var translation = new Translation { Name = dto.Name };
        foreach (var p in dto.Data)
            translation.Add(p.Key, p.Value?.ToString());
        return translation;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Translation value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dto = new TranslationDTO { Name = value.Name, Data = value.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => (object)p.Value) };
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, dto, options);
    }
}
```

And then serialize as follows:

```
var translation = new Translation
{
    Name = "donkey",
    ["key1"] = "value2",
    ["key2"] = "value2",
    ["key3"] = "value3",
};

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new TranslationConverter() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    // Other options as required
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(translation, options);
```

I find it simpler to (de)serialize to a DTO rather than to work directly with `Utf8JsonReader` and `Utf8JsonWriter` as edge cases and naming policies get handled automatically.  Only if performance is critical will I work directly with the reader and writer.

With either approach [`JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy.camelcase) is required to bind `"name"` in the JSON to `Name` in the model.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YSX7TT).