# Mapping multiple JSON property names to the same property in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I'm writing a client that consumes an API (of which I have no control over).  Unfortunately the API's different endpoints are returning inconsistently named JSON fields.  For example one endpoint is returning `errorCode` but another might return `ErrorCode`.

I'm using `System.Text.Json` in my .NET Core application for serialization.  I would like to do something like the following:

```cs
public class MyErrorsResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("errorCode")]
    [JsonPropertyName("ErrorCode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not allowed at compile time and I get the error: `CS0579 Duplicate 'JsonPropertyName' attribute`.

Is there anyway round this problem?  I tried the idea of a 2nd private setter like in: [multiple JsonProperty Name assigned to single property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714050/multiple-jsonproperty-name-assigned-to-single-property). However, it would appear that `System.Text.Json` only serializes public fields and ignores private fields.

Comment: If the only difference is in case you could set `JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true` as shown in [JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60123376/3744182).

Comment: Thanks. Most are case insensitive problems, so this could help with a lot of them (though I'm suspicious how much this will effect performance). But I do have a couple where the string is slightly different.

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714050/multiple-jsonproperty-name-assigned-to-single-property

Comment: There's nothing like that currently, and `System.Text.Json` [does not make its contract resolver public](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).  You could write a custom converter for `MyErrorsResponse` or add multiple properties.  1) How do you want your object to be re-serialized?  2) Are you using .NET Core 3.x or .NET 5?

Comment: Assuming you are working in .NET 5, your most least disruptive option may be to use `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to resolve the majority of the inconsistencies, and use surrogates properties to resolve the remainder.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ww3cOZ.  The other option would be to roll your own custom converter for classes where this is an issue.

Comment: @dbc do you happen to have a sample with custom converter?

Comment: @alhazen - there are many converter samples in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to.  Or see e.g. [Properties of extended dictionary won't show in serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524410/3744182), [System.Text.Json - Deserialize nested object as string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402592/3744182) or [Custom JSON serializer for optional property with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431434/3744182) for examples here.