# How do I handle "extra properties" when binding a JSON structure to a DTO?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I use an API that has JSON like this:

```json
{
    id: 1,
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "user",
    field26461: "abc123"
}
```

I have this C# class

```cs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

They continually add these custom fields. So after shipping my code, there may be a "field32123" in there with some value.

How can I make my code capture these extra fields?

Could I update my class to the following, and somehow have all the fields and their values go into a dictionary?

```cs
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> ExtraFields { get; set; }
}
```

XML has an [XmlAnyElement] attribute that you can use to capture such extra fields.

Comment: Since you don't know the name or type of those extra fields other than names _should_ be a string, a dictionary/map is a good option

Comment: You can use [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute) as shown in e.g. [Properties of extended dictionary won't show in serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524410/3744182) and [Is it possible to catch somehow the remainder of JSON data that didn't match any POCO properties while deserializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63228977/3744182).

Comment: However it needs to be a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, JsonElement>`, and the actual object will end up being of type `JsonElement` even for primitive values.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I found the question asked previously. Do I delete mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields

Comment: Thanks @dbc, that worked

Comment: @Chris - [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields) is tagged for Json.NET, you're asking about System.Text.Json.  No need to delete.